# How the duration in Gatling report is calculated?

Tags: gatling

Listed below is my load details and time duration. My expected duration in Gatling report should be 4500 seconds. Not sure how 3101 seconds is displayed in my gatling report for the below simulation. Can anyone explain me how duration is calculated in gatling report?

```
  setUp(RetrieveCustomerProfile.inject(rampUsers(44) during(8 minutes)).protocols(apis),
        SearchCustomerSummaryWithContact.inject(rampUsers(32) during(8 minutes)).protocols(apis)
        )
        .maxDuration(duration = 75 minutes)
        .assertions(global.successfulRequests.percent.gt(95))
```

Listed below is my report
[image: Gatling report]

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that your users will work for that 75 minutes (or at least 59 since it takes 16 minutes to rump up them)? Max duration will stop simulation after some time it it takes longer, but if it takes less time it won't extend it.

Comment: Hi Mateusz, I haven't done performance testing before and I am new. My requirement for RetrieveCustomerProfile is, I need to ramp users from 0 to 44 for 8 minutes and for SearchCustomerSummaryWithContact is, I need to ramp users from 0 to 32 for 8 minutes and then I need to maintain the same load for 1 hour. Do you think my setup is wrong? If so, can you please help me to update the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

`maxDuration` forcefully stop your test, it doesn't make it last up to this duration.
What drives the test duration is the injection profile and the scenario duration.

Please read the [documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/simulation_setup/#maximum-duration).